# Slider don't show in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

here. http://www.host-bg.eu/ i've a slider i seen it in IE, mozilla, but i cant see in google chrome any ideas?

```
// Set up Sliders
        // **************
        $(function(){

            $('#slider1').anythingSlider({
                theme           : 'metallic',
                easing          : 'easeInOutBack',
                autoPlay        : true,

                navigationFormatter : function(index, panel){
                    return ['Slab', 'Parking Lot', 'Drive', 'Glorius Dawn', 'Bjork?', 'Traffic Circle'][index - 1];
                },
                onSlideComplete : function(slider){
                    // alert('Welcome to Slide #' + slider.currentPage);
                }

            });


            // tooltips for first demo
            $.jatt();

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Tested it and it works. Slider is adding arguments and that's why it doesn't work. http://www.host-bg.eu/

Comment: Try to wrap it into $(document).ready(function(){
       // all the code here
});

Comment: @MikeJohnson $(function() is the same thing as $(document).ready(function()

Comment: @keshav - right...my bad...